# Matlab: Error in inverse operation when implementing Kalman filter

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter, matrix-inverse

I am trying to implement the basic Equations for Kalman filter for the following 1 dimensional AR model:

```
x(t) = a_1x(t-1) + a_2x(t-2) + w(t)  

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t);
```

The KF state space model :

```
x(t+1) = Ax(t) + w(t)

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t)

w(t) = N(0,Q)

v(t) = N(0,R)
```

where

```
 % A - state transition matrix
% C - observation (output) matrix
% Q - state noise covariance
% R - observation noise covariance
% x0 - initial state mean
% P0 - initial state covariance


%%% Matlab script to simulate data and process usiung Kalman for the state
%%% estimation of AR(2) time series.
% Linear system representation
% x_n+1 = A x_n + Bw_n
% y_n = Cx_n + v_n
% w = N(0,Q); v = N(0,R)
clc
clear all

T = 100; % number of data samples
order = 2;
% True coefficients of AR model
  a1 = 0.195;
  a2 = -0.95;

A = [ a1  a2;
      0 1 ];
C = [ 1 0 ];
B = [1;
      0];

 x =[ rand(order,1) zeros(order,T-1)];



sigma_2_w =1;  % variance of the excitation signal for driving the AR model(process noise)
sigma_2_v = 0.01; % variance of measure noise


Q=eye(order);
P=Q;




%Simulate AR model time series, x;



sqrtW=sqrtm(sigma_2_w);
%simulation of the system
for t = 1:T-1
    x(:,t+1) = A*x(:,t) + B*sqrtW*randn(1,1);
end

%noisy observation

y = C*x + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,T);

R=sigma_2_v*diag(diag(x));
R = diag(R);

z = zeros(1,length(y));
z = y;

 x0=mean(y);
for i=1:T-1
[xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q);
[nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z(i), C, R);
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
end

%plot
xhat = xnew';


plot(xhat(:,1),'red');
hold on;
plot(x(:,1));



function [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q)
xpred = A*x0;
Ppred = A*P*A' + Q;
end

function [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, y, C, R)
nu = y - C*xpred; %% innovation
S = R + C*Ppred*C'; %% innovation covariance
end

function [xnew, Pnew] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C)
K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain
xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance
end
```

The code is throwing the error

```
Error using inv
Matrix must be square.

Error in innovation_update (line 2)
K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain

Error in Kalman_run (line 65)
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
```

This is because S matrix is not square. How do I make it square? Is there a problem with the steps before that?

Comment: As per a number of your other questions, I've rolled back the edit here - the answer below was given on the basis of a question featuring code, and it is possible that an answer would not have been given, had the code not been there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the `R` matrix is supposed to be the covariance matrix for the measurement noise.

The following lines:

```
R=sigma_2_v*diag(diag(x));
R = diag(R);
```

Change `R` from a 2x2 diagonal matrix to a 2x1 column vector.

Since your observation `y` is a scalar, the observation noise `v` must also be a scalar. This means `R` is a 1x1 covariance matrix, or simply the variance of the random variable `v`.

You should make `R` a scalar for your code to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The reason I did diagonalization is because in the original implementation https://github.com/cswetenham/pmr/blob/master/toolboxes/lds/kalmansmooth.m , in lines 49-51, the Authors are using the diagonal of the covariance matrix R. My inv(S) is their temp1. I do not understand why they did it, but since the Authors are the pioneer in this field, I followed their procedure. Their code does not throw this error. I am trying to implement it myself, as I think this is the best way to learn rather than copying. If possible, can you please have a look at this?

Comment: @SKM What I'm trying to say is that the `R=diag(R);` line is the problem and you should get rid of it. Before that line, `R` is already a diagonal diagonal it can be left as-is. When `diag` is applied to a matrix, the matrix gets turned into a column vector, so using `diag` taking the `R` you want and turning it into something you don't. Does that make sense? As for the logic behind all this, I'm afraid I'm only familiar with the Kalman filter in passing and don't understand the mathematical details. I was just looking at the form of the equations.

Comment: Since the observation y is a one dimensional vector, R will be a scalar.

Comment: @SKM That makes sense. You would have to change your definition of `R` to be a scalar, then, correct? It would be the variance of `v`?

Comment: I have generated noisy observations from variance of v = 0.01. If R = variance of v then what is the difference? Or should they be the same ( I did not grasp this part from the theory). I ran the code with R = 1 and with R = 0.01. Making R as scalars does not return the prev. error. But, the algorithm does not work, the state estimates are horribly incorrect. What are your thoughts on this? Thank you.

Comment: The code is not performing as it should be, the graph is incorrect. 
xnew  or xhat is a 2 by 2 matrix. Should it not be a vector of time series, otherwise how do I plot?

Comment: @SKM If `y` is a `m x 1` column vector, then `R` should be a `m x m` covariance matrix. Since `m=1` here, `R` should indeed be a scalar since it is the covariance matrix of `v`. I'm afraid I can't help you further without reading more about Kalman filters. You might try reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamic_system_model) in the meantime. I'm not sure what is wrong with your model.